# How do I sanitize form input in Silverstripe CMS

Tags: silverstripe, data-objects

Can someone please direct me to an example of how to sanitise a field from a dataObject BEFORE it gets dumped in the DB?

I don't know where to look.

I want to clean some user input before it is saved to the SiteConfig.

Comment: Generally you don't want to escape data before you write it - instead you should escape before outputting. Do you have more information on your use case?

Comment: @ajshort I want to convert to lowercase and trim non alpha characters before going into db.

Comment: @ajshort for the purpose of saving twitter hashtags to check against when parsing api return

Comment: Is this referring to the CMS or a fronted form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize saving-behaviour of a `Page`, `DataObject` or `SiteConfig` using the [`onBeforeWrite`](http://doc.silverstripe.com/framework/en/topics/datamodel#onbeforewrite) function.

The function is triggered when calling `write()` to save the object to the database. This includes saving a page in the CMS or altering a ModelAdmin record.

Here is an example for Silverstripe 3.1 of using `onBeforeWrite` on a SiteConfig Extension to strip characters and convert characters to lowercase on a text field:

**SiteConfig onBeforeWrite example**

```php
class CustomSiteConfig extends DataExtension {

    private static $db = array(
        'TwitterUsername' => 'Text'
    );

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) {
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new TextField('TwitterUsername', 'Twitter Username'));
    }

    public function onBeforeWrite() {
        $this->owner->TwitterUsername = strtolower($this->owner->TwitterUsername);
        $this->owner->TwitterUsername = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9]/", '', $this->owner->TwitterUsername);

        parent::onBeforeWrite();
    }
}
```

Note: For the above example to work the `CustomSiteConfig` extensions needs to be applied to the `SiteConfig`. This can either be done through a *yml* config file or through a *_config.php* file.

**mysite/_config/config.yml**

```
---
Name: site
After: 'framework/*','cms/*'
---

# ...

# SiteConfig Extension

SiteConfig:
  extensions:
    - CustomSiteConfig

# ...
```

Or

**mysite/_config.php**

```php
global $project;
$project = 'mysite';

// ...

SiteConfig::add_extension('CustomSiteConfig');

// ...
```

Comment: Dont forget, this won't run automatically. You need to load it from _config.php in my site or one of your module, ie: SiteConfig::add_extension('CustomSiteConfig'); You can also load it via a yml file inside a _config folder.

Comment: Thanks @elliot_at_silverstripe. I've added that note into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is taken care of automatically.

`$dataObject->Title = 'te"st'; // This will become "te\"st"
$dataObject->write();`

More information about this can be found in the docs: http://doc.silverstripe.com/framework/en/topics/security